# World Locking Tools + Azure Spatial Anchors sample running on Android - issue with changing position of SpacePins

Tags: c#, android-augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm currently having issues trying to run the "PinTestSofa" scene (unity) on Android.
This one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mixed-reality/world-locking-tools/documentation/howtos/samples/wlt_asa_sample 
I followed all the recommended steps concerning gradle and enabling wi-fi, but I still can't move a pin to a different location.
Whenever I try to move a Space Pin, it always comes back to the starting position.
I reach the "ready" state, however at lauch I get a "Not ready: No ASA manager" notification.

Currently using:
Unity - 2020.3.36f1
MRTK Foundation - 2.7.3
WLT ASA, Core, and Samples - 1.5.0
ASA SDK for Android - 2.10.0
ASA SDK Core - 2.10.0

Any advice on how to proceed?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the Vertical Displacement field on Anchor Graph Visual script (default value was -1, and I changed it to 0 for testing purposes). It worked. Now I'm able to change the position of the Space Spins and see the spongy anchors as well.